# Does it make sense to separate Rails API and Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have a project that involves both mobile and web clients. The mobile clients will mainly get content and post user updates, while the web client is mainly for creating content. As such, the web client and API share a lot of the same models and validation.

I am trying to decide the best approach in this case:

1. JSON-only Rails API + separate Rails web client that calls API.
2. Single Rails app with separation of API and client side (somehow).

The pro for me in terms of option N°1 is the separation of concerns, as I can work on the API while someone else do the web client. The con seems to be lots of duplicated code in terms of validation.

N°2 could make more sense in terms of reducing code duplication but it would get messy if more than one person is working on the same code base and setting up a process to resolve code conflicts is not something I want to do at this point since we're an early stage startup and want to get out something quickly.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Hi there Alex! I think your post might be a better fit for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) - it deals with more conceptual questions like this one as opposed to more concrete question/answer posts on [so].

Comment: Would you consider something like react-s where you can have the best of both worlds? The front end for the web application can be written in Javascript and it will use APIs to build the view. Its fast. Where as the mobile app will use the APIs to post its request. May be it too simplistic answer?

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is use ONE rails application for API and Web Interface

To separate those parts, just create a namespace for API like it's described there http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2013/06/13/building-awesome-rails-apis-part-1/

Comment: Can you point out any potential issue with having both the API and web app in the same application? In terms of both performance and maintainability

Comment: @AlexN. Potentially, there's no issues. If your application will be under a highload, you can easily add more server instances for you application and add a load-balancer to spread the highload over them.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in one.

> The con seems to be lots of duplicated code in terms of validation.

No, you would not have duplication the validation happens in the model, which is shared by your API <=> web controllers. Of course, you will have separate implementations for the actual authorization/session handling (if you have those), but these will not likely be duplicate but a bit different for your two access layers.