# Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've moved all my controllers, helpers, models, views and assets under a web folder. And now I'm getting an uninitialized constant HomeController error. How can I reflect this change to my routes?

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index', module: 'web'
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> uninitialized constant HomeController

You have `root 'home#index', module: 'web'` and as you moved your controller under the web, the **class name** of the controller should be **prefixed with module name** like `Web::`

```
class Web::HomeController
end
```

**OR**

If you wish not to prefix with `Web::` module, you can just change

```
root 'home#index', module: 'web'
```

to

```
root 'home#index', path: '/web/home'
```

For more info read [*Controller namespacing*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: Thanks but Unfortunately Im still getting the error. Please note that I have move the controller folder itself under the web folder

Comment: @SpongebobJunior You are doing it wrong. It should be like this *controllers folder --> web folder ---> home_controller.rb*

Comment: Im trying to separate API and Web into its own folders i.e all web related will be under a web folder and all web services will be under api folder. I cant do that on Ruby on Rails?

Comment: @SpongebobJunior: not like this, no. If your web and api are really that separate (which sounds a bit strange), you could try extracting them as rails engines.

Comment: @SpongebobJunior AFAIK, you can't do it like this. You can separate controller files by namespacing and defining the namespaced routes which will map those controller actions.

Comment: @SpongebobJunior You can see this SO post for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810764/does-it-make-sense-to-separate-rails-api-and-rails-app

Comment: Thanks for the info Im just going to separate them